# Ajax append to an already loaded dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i have an ajax dialog that I loaded a page into and I just want to append an html warning at the top and am having extreme difficulties appending to the already created dialog.  This is what i have:

```
function Dialog_Ajax(title, source, buttons) {
    _DialogContent.html("<div id='warning'></div><div id='dialogContentInner'></div>");
    _DialogContent.find("div").load(source, Dialog_FixSize, function() {
        $("#warning").append("sadfsadf");
    });

    Dialog_Open(title, false, (buttons) ? buttons : _DialogButtons_Close);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: (1) `.find("div")` will select both divs, `id='warning'` and `id='dialogContentInner'`. Try `.find("#dialogContentInner")`.
(2) Presumably you want the dialog to open after the asynchronously derived content has loaded. If so, then move `Dialog_Open(...)` inside the `.load()` callback.